# Reading the right amount of data out of a pipe when your receiving output from execvp

Tags: c, pipe, execvp

This is just a small part of a bigger program but Im trying to get the output from execvp 
I have execvp set up correctly with `dup2` that directs it into a pipe.
My problem comes when it comes to using read to read the full length of the pipe I don't know how large the output of `execvp` is each time cause it can be different depending on the input.

```
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        close(fd[0]);
        dup2(fd[1], 1);
        execvp(msg.v,(char *[]){msg.v,NULL});
    } else if (pid > 0) {
        close(fd[1]);
        read(fd[0],msg.v,....);
    }
```

I have tried a few different sizes for read but its either not enough or I end up getting random junk at the end I know you can use popen and a few other things from stdio but its required for the assignment that we do not use them Im blanking on other ways to go about getting the output.

A little more useless info the whole program is part of a server. Im making a server and a client.. start the server give the client a terminal command it sends it over to the server over a INET stream and sending the output back to the client to display output all without stdio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pay attention to how much data `read` returns into your buffer. While `read` is returning positive numbers, you have more data. When the program is done, it will close its end of the `pipe`, and your `read` will return `0`.

```
} else if (pid > 0) {
    close(fd[1]);
    ssize_t r = read(fd[0],buf,bufsz);
    if (r > 0) do {
        /* ... do something with r bytes in buf */
        r = read(fd[0],buf,bufsz);
    } while (r > 0);
    if (r < 0) {
        perror("read");
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

If you see `read` give an "Interrupted system call" error, then you have encountered the `EINTR` case that caf mentioned. You restart your `read` again in that case.

```
        for (;;) {
            r = read(fd[0],buf,bufsz);
            if (r != -1 || errno != EINTR) break;
        }
```

I am assuming you are not doing non-blocking I/O, so you will not encounter the "Resource temporarily unavailable" message.

Comment: I didnt mention this but we can use stdio that doesnt preform IO so I was able to loop through and use sprintf to piece together my message thanks this helped!

Answer (score 1):

You keep reading until `read()` returns `0`, which indicates EOF (or -1 with `errno` set to a permanent error, which is anything other than `EAGAIN` or `EINTR`).

You must not ignore the return value of `read()` - it tells you how many bytes it has returned.  That's why you're seeing "junk" at the end of the buffer - in those cases `read()` was not filling the whole buffer, and you ignored the return value so you don't know how much it actually returned.